# tkinter extract data from txt file to button widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

for all the information that ive gather this is the result that come out with.. it has a txt startup file..(see images)..open it extract strings convert it into a list then it convert into float print data to shell n close txt file(save data) then writes data to the button widget.. changes to existing data made by simple dialog.. it convert the data back into strings.. but.. im trying to find ways to overwrite the existing data using the converted strings from simple dialog entry data.. to the existing txt startup file in a specific area or lines.. anything is helpful tq :)

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

def onChange(i):     
    btn_list[i].config(text='Updating...',bg='red')  
    btn_list[i].grid(in_=root,row=rw[i],column=2)
    ans=tk.simpledialog.askfloat('Updating....', 'What is the current price?')
    if ans:
        btn_list[i].config(text='RM {:,.2f}'.format(ans))
        btn_list[i].config(bg='yellow')
        c=str(ans)
        fw=open('dataTest.txt','w')
        fw.close()

root=Tk()

Title=['Item','Unit','Price']
Item=['Kopi O','Teh O','Teh Tarik']
Unit= '1 cup'
cl=[0,1,2]
rw=[1,2,3]
btn_list=[]
fr=open('dataUpdate.txt','r')

with open('dataUpdate.txt') as input_file:
    text=input_file.read()
    strings=text.split()
    number=[float(item) for item in strings]
    print(number)
    fr.close()

for k in range(3):
    btnT1=tk.Button(root,text=Title[k],width=12,bg='light green')
    btnT1.grid(in_=root,row=0,column=cl[k])

for x in range(3):
    btnT2=tk.Button(root,text=Item[x],width=12)
    btnT2.grid(in_=root,row=rw[x],column=0)

for y in range(3):
    btnT3=tk.Button(root,text=Unit,width=12)
    btnT3.grid(in_=root,row=rw[y],column=1)             

for z in range(3):
    btnT4=tk.Button(root,text=('RM {:,.2f}'.format(number[z])),bg='yellow',width=12,\
                command=lambda i=z:onChange(i))
    btnT4.grid(in_=root,row=rw[z],column=2)
    btn_list.append(btnT4)

root.mainloop()
```

[dataUpdate.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDMt3.png)

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly you want to store the values you change during runtime, in `dataUpdate.txt` . You already create a `list` containing the numbers, when you read the file. Use this `list` and update it with the new values. Then write each entry in the list to the file.

To update an entry in the `list` called `number`, the syntax is:

```
number[index] = value
```

Your onChange function will be something like:

```
def onChange(i):
    btn_list[i].config(text='Updating...', bg='red')
    btn_list[i].grid(in_=root, row=rw[i], column=2)
    ans = tk.simpledialog.askfloat('Updating....', 'What is the current price?')
    if ans:
        btn_list[i].config(text='RM {:,.2f}'.format(ans))
        btn_list[i].config(bg='yellow')
        number[i] = ans
        with open('dataUpdate.txt', 'w') as file:
            for entry in number:
                file.write(str(entry) + "\n")
```

By the way, when you use:

```
with open('dataUpdate.txt') as input_file:
```

you don't need to open and close the file in any other way, as this is handled by `with`, so you can remove these lines in your code:

```
fr=open('dataUpdate.txt','r')
    fr.close()
```